# Crystal Reports Server 2008 - How do you create a APS Logon Token programmatically in .Net

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

Could some one guide me to create a APS logon token in .Net programmatically? I need to use this token for URL reporting....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Shared Function Authenticate (account As String, password As String, serverName As String, authenticationType As String) As String

  Dim sessionManager As New SessionMgr
  Dim enterpriseSession As EnterpriseSession

  Try

    enterpriseSession = sessionManager.Logon(account, password, serverName, authenticationType)

    'any client computer, 120 minutes, 1000 logons
    Return enterpriseSession.LogonTokenMgr.CreateLogonTokenEx("", 120, 1000)

  Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex

  End Try


End Function
```