# Visual Studio 2017 and SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I have downloaded and installed the **visual studio 2017 community** and after that I have downloaded and Installed **Crystal Report Support pack 20 (v.13.0.20.2399)**.

I opened **visual studio 2017** and create a new project, then I right clicked my project after that I clicked add item.

I look for crystal report .rpt, but it's not showing.

Am I the only one experienced this? Is there anything I need to download?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate SAP Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902740/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per below link you downloaded perfect link, but it says that crystal report will available in June. I don't know its support, but ask in sap support.

[How to integrate SAP Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902740/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2017)

https://answers.sap.com/questions/68489/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2017-availabilit.html

Read this link, according to this need version 21.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2110984.aspx?VS+2017+and+Crystal+Reports

Comment: Thank you so much for your help sir.

Comment: The download link does not work. You can use link https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/#visual-studio-direct-download-link