# What versions of the .NET Framework does CR for VS support?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I've got a really old `ASP.NET WebForms` app that I am tasked with maintaining.

I'm not one of the original developers. Don't even know who they were. 
Anyway, they used Crystal Reports for the reports they wrote for it. And they wrote it to use .NET Framework 2, in whatever version of Visual Studio that came out with it.

I'd like to upgrade it to `.NET 4.5 using Visual Studio 2015`. However, I don't have Crystal Reports installed on my PC.

We do have an installer for Crystal Reports for Visual Studio, which I've just learned came out with Visual Studio 2010.

I'm hoping that will support .NET 4.5 or at least .NET 4. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not tell crystal report version which you have, so not exactly tell anything.

But yes, [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) is list of Visual Studio with Crystal report supported page.

Crystal report is related to visual studio, not .net framework. but visual studio based on .net framework. For VS2010 does not have 4.5 framework and also not supported.

I suggest use Visual Studio 2017 with Crystal report. See my answers in

[Visual Studio 2017 and Crystal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794948/visual-studio-2017-and-crystal/43797202#43797202)

Or If you wish go to VS2015 : 
[Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2015 Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273125/crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2015-community/37274765#37274765)

Comment: I'd like to move to VS 2017. My boss does not. Therefore, we'll use VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

VS for crystal report has a `compatibility version` using VS 2015.

I am not really sure what version of `Crystal report`, do you want to install. The important is, if you `done installing` the crystal report you may `restart your pc` and try to test it by right click on

> Project -> Add new item -> Crystal Report

if work then that is the version you need. Because in my experienced, VS 2012 i was done almost `3 to 4` times installing of `CReport for VS2012` then it become fine and working.. Just try till it works.

Good luck!