# The 'Crystal Reports Tools Package' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I have installed the latest SAP Crystal Reports SP 21 for Visual Studio 2017 and receive the following error when opening a project in visual studio:

> The 'Crystal Reports Tools Package' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file '...'.
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

[image: SAP Crystal Reports Visual Studio Error]

The following entry appeared in the file `ActivityLog.xml`:

```
<entry>
    <record>852</record>
    <time>2018/06/20 12:18:32.507</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>No InprocServer32 registered for package [Crystal Reports Tools Package]</description>
    <guid>{FE73BB80-53F4-4AD0-A5F9-6A0BCE662292}</guid>
    <hr>8007007e</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
    <path>c:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\CRVsPackage.dll</path>
</entry>
```

Since I can't view or edit SAP Crystal Report *.rpt files: How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You reinstall it. Failing that, reinstall VS.

Comment: You can check this link for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902740/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2017/52733946

Comment: @Will Reinstall of extension did not work. Still got this error almost one year later

Comment: @NadimHossainSonet the provided question did not provide any solution for this problem.

Comment: @WoIIe Sorry, I was trying to provide some other link, but by mistake provided you this link. Basically, you have to remove crystal report from the solution and then build and then again add the assemblies. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, Crystal Reporting package is corrupted in your case. You can try to reinstall the package, otherwise remove the existing VS 2017 completely and install it back again.