# crystal report problem in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

Since long time i am facing the problem regarding crystal report in visual studio 2017. I install and uninstall many time sap crystal report in my pc but it is not able to see "Reporting-->Crystal report" option in my "Add New item" of project. As per some suggestion provided on net i used sap service pack 21 for visual studio 2017 but still problem not solved. i have requirement of crystal report in my app so please suggest about this problem. Please find attachment for more detail about problem.

thank you,

have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try 13.0.23 or 13.0.24 service pack.

- Make sure to install the CR first and don't check the runtime checkbox at the end,
- Now install the runtime.

If this doesn't work try

- Cleaning and rebuilding your solution
- Restarting your PC
- Try installing the 32-bits versions if you haven't already

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902740/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2017) , might help you.