# Microsoft visual studio 2017 and installed SP21 for crystal reports but reporting option is not available

Tags: visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

I have a requirement to edit .rpt files.
I have installed Visual studio 2017 and installed crystalreports SP21 by referring the below page.

[How to integrate SAP Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902740/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2017)

I have downloaded the SP21 from this website and installed in my machine. The SP21 setup which I ran is CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_21.msi . Is that correct one?
https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html

I couldn't get the reporting option under C# items in my forms project(Solutionsexplorer->Add->Newitem->Visual C# items) in Visual studio 2017 even after installing above mentioned SP21.

Please anyone help me how to get the reporting option enabled to edit crystal report (.rpt) files.
or please tell me the right website to download the service packs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for ***SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio***: https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-crystal-reports-visual-studio-trial.html

Comment: Can I download SP21 from that site or the higher versions.?