# Crystal Report 13.0.31.4010 installed but did not integrated with Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

I had Windows 7 64bit. I used visual studio 2017 and I needed to create report so I installed crystal report for visual studio. It worked perfectly and I created many reports by using it.

Now I bought a new laptop. It has Windows 10 64bit. After I installed visual studio 2017, It was needed to install crystal report for visual studio again so I can continue working on the project. But this time after installing the crystal report, it was not integrated with the visual studio.

I do not find crystal report option in "Add New Item". Also I cannot edit my reports which I already made before.
Whenever I click on the report to edit, it opens a view and track your downloads page in internet explorer and nothing happened then

My crystal report version is 13.0.4010

I have also installed Runtime Engine of same version

My Visual Studio is 2017 Professional

[Crystal report in add or remove programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHhxQ.jpg)

[When I click on any report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8ghu.jpg)

Comment: When you installed Crystal Reports for Visual Studio, what was the version you installed?  For Visual Studio 2017 you need SP21 if I remember correctly.  If you installed any other version, it won't work with your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I was using the latest one. Well I uninstalled it and Installed Service pack 21. But the result is still same.

Comment: Have you seen this related question yet?  There are a number of suggestions in the various answers and comments that may help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902740/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Yeah R.McMillan Thanks. I have tried all of these but no success. Well I just tired installing visual studio and crystal report SP 22 on brother's laptop, he still has windows 7 running. I did not get any problem in integration, everything went fine and I edited my reports for now. So I think it is making problems for windows 10 or my OS has issues. Now I am going to install virtual box with windows 7 for the projects which use crystal report.